# I need .NET Core 6.0 but my Visual Studio is showing just 2.2

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

[image: Visual Studio]

I need .NET Core 6.0 but my Visual Studio is showing just 2.2 ...

Comment: Which **version** of Visual Studio do you have? .NET 6 works only in VS 2022. And have you downloaded and installed the [.NET 6 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) on your machine? This is needed so that .NET 6 becomes available as a target framework in VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

if you have visual studio 2022 and you don't see version 6

1-open visual studio installer and update it.

2-download .NET 6 SDK